# Qual a diferença entre "ON" e "USING"?

Tags: sql

Considerando duas maneiras de se declarar um `INNER JOIN`, temos:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 INNER JOIN tabela2 ON tabela1.cd_tabela1 = tabela2.cd_tabela1;
```

e

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 INNER JOIN tabela2 USING(cd_tabela1);
```

Qual a diferença entre os dois? Além do *inner join*, existe alguma diferença se for considerado outros *joins* como o *right outer join*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Resposta**:

O **ON** é utilizado quando se tem nomes de colunas diferentes ou iguais entre as tabelas, já o **USING** é utilizando quando ambas as tabelas compartilham uma coluna com o mesmo nome exato.

Para apresentar as diferenças entre os JOIN vou mostrar um exemplo, utilizando as seguintes tabelas de dados abaixo, cujo nome do campo é igual ao da tabela:

```
A  |  B
---+---
1  |  3
2  |  4
3  |  5
4  |  6
```

**INNER JOIN**

É uma junção interna usando as consultas equivalentes resultantes da interseção das duas tabelas, ou seja, as duas linhas que as duas tabelas tem em comum.

```
select * from A INNER JOIN B ON A.A = B.B;

A | B
--+--
3 | 3
4 | 4
```

**LEFT OUTER JOIN**

É uma junção externa à esquerda que resultará em todas as linhas de A, além de todas as linhas comuns em B.

```
select * from A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.A = B.B;

A |  B  
--+-----
1 | null
2 | null
3 |    3
4 |    4
```

**RIGHT OUTER JOIN**

É uma junção externa à direita que resultará em todas as linhas de B, além de todas as linhas comuns em A.

```
select * from A RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A.A = B.B;

 A   |  B  
-----+----
3    |  3
4    |  4
null |  5
null |  6
```

**FULL OUTER JOIN**

É uma junção externa completa lhe dará a união de A e B, ou seja, todas as linhas de uma e todas as linhas de B. Se uma linha A não tem um correspondência em B, o valor de B será nulo, e vice- versa.

```
select * from A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.A = B.B;

 A   |  B  
-----+-----
   1 | null
   2 | null
   3 |    3
   4 |    4
null |    6
null |    5
```

Comment: Okay, mas há alguma diferença nos dados retornados quando se utiliza o `USING`?

Comment: @Patrick como havia dito a diferença se dar nome dos campos so isso... nesse exemplo não é recomendado usar using pois o nome das colunas das tabelas são diferentes.. A.A != B.B caso o nome do campo da tabela de B fosse A.. entao using (A).

Comment: @Patrick mas em termos praticos nao há diferença nenhuma...