# Agrupamento do maior ID por linha não retoma valores corretos

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
Tabela: tabela_1

id   | id_pessoas | id_empreitadas
-----------------------------------
4357 | 3776       | 37
3949 | 3776       | 3
```

Tenho a consulta:

```
SELECT id_pessoas , MAX(id) max_id, id_empreitadas FROM tabela_1 GROUP BY id_pessoas
```

Esta consulta retoma:

```
id   | id_pessoas | id_empreitadas
-----------------------------------
4357 | 3776       | 3
```

Não consigo perceber porque é que retoma o valor `3` no `id_empreitadas` e não o `37`. Podem-me ajudar?

Comment: O que você precisa é o maior valor em id_empreitadas ou precisa do valor relacionado ao registro que possui o maior id? Isso não está claro na pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade nem trás nada, pois o `GROUP BY` vai dar erro.

Comment: Basicamente pq não é assim que funciona. Em SQLite a linha retornada é sempre a mesma em todos os campos. Em MySQL pode retornar qualquer uma. @rbz [dependendo da configuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164515/70). Conforme for, precisa ANY_VALUE( ) pra retornar as outras, sem strict é como se tivesse aplicado ANY_VALUE() pras sem agrupamento

Comment: A query enviada está incorreta, porque no group by deveria colocar todas as infos do select. Manda a query real que você usou que retornou esse registro.

Comment: O que eu quero são os dados da linha que contém o maior valor de 'id'. Quando o query é executado, ele retoma a linha com o maior id, mas o valor que retoma na coluna 'id_empreitadas'  é o valor de outra linha. O objectivo é obter a coluna 'id_empreitadas' no maior valor de 'id'.

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que nada garante em MySQL que as colunas sem agregação vão retornar da mesma linha.

Inclusive, como observado pelo @rbz nos comentários, [dependendo da configuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164515/70) do MySQL dará erro por misturar agregação com linha normal.

Uma possível solução é fazer um `JOIN` entre a tabela, e uma virtual resultante do MAX dela agrupado.

Primeiro, fazemos essa tabela virtual com:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM tabela_1 GROUP BY id_pessoas
```

que retorna uma lista de IDs com o critério desejado (o maior de cada grupo).

Depois fazemos um `SELECT` das colunas todas que queremos, e um `JOIN` usando o retorno do `SELECT` anterior como uma tabela virtual, ficando assim:

```
SELECT
   id_pessoas,
   id,
   id_empreitadas
FROM
   tabela_1 a
   JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM tabela_1 GROUP BY id_pessoas) b
   USING (id);
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/381f4/1)**.

Comment: Uma referência ao `USING`: [Qual a diferença entre “ON” e “USING”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34480/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-on-e-using)

Answer (score 2):

Há outra forma para além da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/422502/7210) que o @Bacco deu que é usar o `IN`:

```
SELECT
   id_pessoas,
   id,
   id_empreitadas
FROM
   tabela_1
   WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM tabela_1 GROUP BY id_pessoas);
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf1328/2)

Comment: Se alguem se interessar: https://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/ - Resumindo exageradamente, de acordo com o autor do artigo, o planner acaba otimizando o IN para ficar com o mesmo plano de execução do Join pra aproveitar índices no final, evitando repetir o SELECT a cada linha.