# Como retornar apenas a linha da última manutenção de cada equipamento?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relatório

Estou implementando o modulo de relatório em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo, porém não consigo chegar onde quero, meu cenário:

Tenho uma tabela equipamento, ligada por chave estrangeira a uma outra tabela chamada manutenção, na tabela manutenção eu cadastro apenas a data da manutenção e ligo ao equipamento desejado

Quando tento retornar uma *query* para o relatório, caso exista duas datas de manutenção, ele retorna duas *rows* do mesmo equipamento, mudando só a data de manutenção...

Eu queria que retornasse apenas a data da ULTIMA manutenção, mas não estou conseguindo.

Estou usando a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM equipamento 
INNER JOIN manutencao ON id_equipamento = id_equipamento_manutencao
```

Print de como está retornando no relatório:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Entendo "última" como sendo a data mais recente, utilize a cláusula GROUP BY e a função de agregação MAX: `SELECT equipamento.id_equipamento, max(manutencao.data) FROM equipamento 
INNER JOIN manutencao ON id_equipamento = id_equipamento_manutencao
GROUP BY equipamento.id_equipamento`.

Comment: De qualquer forma, convém pesquisar aqui no site, pois esta questão já foi feita de algumas maneiras diferentes. Se nenhuma servir, pode [edit] com um [mcve] (estrutura - só dos campos relevantes - dados de exemplo, resultado pretendido e resultado obtido com estes dados) Vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70) para entender melhor o site e como formular. Aproveitando para trocar a imagem por texto - estou tentando localizar problema similar pra indicar link.

Comment: Sobre o _"Vocês fecham a pergunta na velocidade da luz, para atrapalhar vocês são rápidos, para ajudar vocês fogem."_  @Matheus sua resposta é um bom exemplo de porque fechamos enquanto 
 faltam detalhes. Saiu um monte de complicação (e não resolve a duplicidade, ou seja não é ajuda) até agora. Estamos ajudando o autor e a comunidade para garantir qualidade, que é o objetivo do site. Leia o Guia indicado no comment anterior para entender melhor.

Comment: Luis, acho que isso pode ajudar, é um caso similar (sintoma diferente, mas mesma solução) e uma explicação  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422495/

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos pelas resposta, consegui resolver meu problema !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A principal falha é não identificar de onde vem as variaveis na cláusula ON. Aqui identifico as tabelas por uma letra e vinculo as variáveis a respectiva tabela.
Também alterei de INNER para LEFT JOIN pois toda manutenção deveestar vinculada a um equipamento. Mas caso queira manter manutenções sem equipamentos vinculados sua consulta não está errada.

```sql
SELECT 
    E.ID,
    MAX(M.data)
FROM 
    equipamento as E
    LEFT JOIN manutencao as M ON E.id_equipamento = M.id_equipamento_manutencao 
GROUP BY
    E.id_equipamento
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma CTE para selecionar apenas as ultimas manutenções e então utilizar no JOIN, acaba ficando mais semântico.

Exemplo (lembre-se de adequar às tabelas existentes):

Aqui um [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4360be/8):

```sql
with ultima_manutencao as 
(
  select 
     max(m.data_manutencao) data_ultima_manut
     , m.equip_id
  from 
    manut m
  group by 
    m.equip_id
)
select 
  * 
from 
  equip e
  join ultima_manutencao um on um.equip_id = e.id
```